# Unexpected Bit.Reverse() result

Tags: go, math, bit-manipulation

In the algorithm task, I need to reverse the bits.
Here is the example:
[image]

But when I use `"math/bits"` `bits.Reverse32(9)` the result is different 2415919104.

The link: https://play.golang.org/p/Lf6qlOTMTXz

Comment: This is what you should be doing `^uint32(9)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> // Reverse32 returns the value of x with its bits in reversed order.
> func Reverse32(x uint32) uint32 {...}

e.g.: 1234 became: 4321

What you are looking for is all bits toggle:

```
    var u uint32 = 9
    fmt.Printf("%#032b\n", u) // 0b00000000000000000000000000001001

    n := u ^ 0xffff_ffff
    fmt.Printf("%#032b\n", n) // 0b11111111111111111111111111110110
```

Try [it](https://play.golang.org/p/4m5G4934zoM):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/bits"
)

func main() {
    var u uint32 = 9
    fmt.Printf("%#032b\n", u) // 0b00000000000000000000000000001001

    n := u ^ 0xffff_ffff
    fmt.Printf("%#032b\n", n) // 0b11111111111111111111111111110110

    u = bits.Reverse32(u)
    fmt.Printf("%#032b\n", u) // 0b10010000000000000000000000000000
}
```

Comment: And see Bitwise NOT `^u`: https://yourbasic.org/golang/bitwise-operator-cheat-sheet/